# Split groups in bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2, ggforce

I have a dataframe with values corresponding to two separate groups evaluated over time. Mock data below:

```
Gene Name. Sample S1. Sample S2. Sample S3. Sample R1. Sample R2. Sample R3.
Gene 1         4          5          3          3          39        44
Gene 2         4         100        33          3          32        14
```

I melted my dataframe and compiled summary stats using the summarySE function. I then plotted my data using the following script:

```
plot = ggplot(tgastats2, aes(x=Gene Name, y=value, fill=Sample)) 
  + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se),
                  + width=.2,
                  + position=position_dodge(.9))
```

What I would like to do is plot the values of S1-3 grouped together and R1-3 on the same plot separated with some space. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Patrick.  Unfortunately, what you have given us so far isn't very helpful.  It's not a simple, self-contained example.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) may help you create one.  In particular, posting the result of `dput(tgastats2)` or `dput(head(tgastats2))` (if it's large) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the data in a reproducible way:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Gene_name=c('Gene 1', 'Gene 2'),
  Sample.S1=c(4,4), Sample.S2=c(5,100), Sample.S3=c(3,33),
  Sample.R1=c(3,3), Sample.R2=c(39,32), Sample.R3=c(44,14)
)
```

Now, for a solution.  As you indicated, we need to "melt" the dataset.  My preference is to use `gather()` from `dplyr`, but `melt()` works in a similar manner:

```
df1 <- df %>% gather(key='Sample', value='value', -Gene_name)
```

In order for `ggplot2` to know that you want to group it in the manner you indicate, you will need to categorize the data.  R and `ggplot` are not smart enough to understand S1, S2, and S3 belong together, so you have to tell R how that can be done.  There are likely a lot of ways to separate and categorize.  Without seeing your actual melted df, `tgastats2`, I'll have to assume it's similar to the example posted.  I'm going to use the fact that all samples R1-R3 contain a capital "R", whereas the others do not:

```
df1$my_group <- ifelse(grepl('R',df1$Sample),'R','S')
```

Then you can plot:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=Gene_name, y=value, fill=my_group)) +
  geom_col(position='dodge', color='black')
```

[image]

Hm... that doesn't look right.  What's going on?  Well, `ggplot` is separating based on `df1$my_group`, but there are 3 values in each of those groups.  You can separate those out by using the `group=` aesthetic in addition to the `fill=` aesthetic and `ggplot` will separate them out completely:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=Gene_name, y=value, fill=my_group, group=Sample)) +
  geom_col(position='dodge', color='black')
```

[image]

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Is there any chance I would be able to add labels underneath the bars from the df1$Sample column?

Comment: Never mind. I was able to figure it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: could you share how?